# What's the best way to get around the lack of transparency in WixUI background images?

Tags: wix

I'm using the Feature Tree UI, with a couple of custom dialogs. One of these has checkboxes on it. These checkboxes cannot be made to have transparent backgrounds, meaning I've had to colour in my background image the default background colour so that there aren't visible boxes around the checkboxes.

However, different versions of Windows have different default colouring! If I match the colour on Windows 7, it looks bad on XP, etc. Since the background images are Bitmaps, I can't make them transparent. What can I do to get around this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [WiX tutorial UI revisited](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/well-done) chapter:

> And a common complaint: no, the checkbox can't have a transparent
>   background. If you have a bitmap in the background, it will be ugly,
>   just like in our example above. **The only workaround is to reduce the
>   width of the checkbox to the actual box itself and to place an
>   additional static text (these can be made transparent) adjacent to it.**

This workaround has a side effect, although: in order to turn the checkbox on and off, you should click exactly in the box area, not the text. Comparing to the rest of Windows Installer UI limitations, it's slightly annoying :-)

Comment: @Tom Medley, have you been pressing F5 on this page all this time? That's the fastest points I got on SO so far :-)

Comment: I just tried using a PNG file with transparency, and it works fine. Will I face any issue if I do that?

Comment: @ViniciusRocha I haven't heard about any improvements in this area. Perhaps, something changed in Windows Installer since then.

Answer (score 2):

Windows installer supports 32-bit bitmaps (ARGB), which means that the bitmap can be made transparent to show the default windows background color. This means, once your (not transparent) check-box is placed on top, you won't see the ugly box around the text, because it's the same color.

Note that windows photo viewer and the thumbnail preview in explorer DONT support transparencies, so you'll have to build and run your installer to see it working =D.

I used gimp to export to BMP with a transparency and it worked just fine with WIX.